# Does Mule CXF proxy service overwrites the soap:address location attribute of wsdl

Tags: wsdl, mule

This is how part of my Mule 3.3.0 flow is:

```
<flow name="soapService">
        <http:inbound-endpoint address="${my.service.address}" exchange-pattern="request-response">
            <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:order.wsdl" namespace="http://abc.com/services/order" service="OrderService"
                enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
            </cxf:proxy-service>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
...

</flow>
```

No matter, whatever I specify in my order.wsdl `<soap:address location="http://server.com/order">`, this is being overwritten by `${my.service.address}` value specified in `<http://inbound-endpoint address="${my.service.address}">`

If I check in my wsdl in `classes` folder, it has the correct value in `location` attribute of `<soap:address>` element but when try to see the wsdl from browser, value is replaced with `address` of `<http:inbound-endpoint>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature not a bug :)

Because your are using a CXF proxy you *want* the SOAP address to be rewritten to the inbound HTTP endpoint address so that clients consuming the WSDL exposed by Mule will send SOAP requests through the proxy and not directly to whatever SOAP address was initially in the WSDL.

Comment: So many undocumented Features of CXF proxy :). Thanks for your insight David

Comment: Hi @david, further on this similar setup, if there are requests via https, coming through a load-balancer which off loads the ssl, we found the returned wsdl has its service address in http protocol, how should we do to modify this value back to https? we are using cxf:proxy and http-inbound-endpoint

Comment: Hey @JamesJiang - You should ask this as a new question, to have more eyes on it and have a better chance to be answered. In this new question, don't forget to specify if the load-balancer adds a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (or equivalent) to the requests it dispatches.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDossot, I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823230/mule-cxfproxy-endpoint-behind-load-balancer-uses-http-in-soap-service-address