# Mule cxf:proxy endpoint behind load-balancer uses http in soap service address

Tags: cxf, mule, load-balancing

As title, we had a simple service design that uses a cxf:proxy endpoint inside an http-inbound enpoint, and the Mule server is behind load-balancer which does ssl offloading.

When user requested with `https`://url?wsdl, in the returned wsdl, we found mule writes the service address in `http`. Is there any way that we could change it to https here?

We are using mule 3.5.2 here.

PS. The Load-balancer is F5 and belongs to 'network team', we could ask for the X-Forwarded-Proto header, but only if we confirm it will work? (I have no clue, also need help here please)

Comment: What Mule version are you using?

Comment: Found this old thread: http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/wsdl_generation_with_ssl_termination I can't find the patch in the Mule source code so it doesn't bode well for your situation. Maybe it's been added to CXF directly? You can give it a quick try by manually adding `X-Forwarded-Proto` to a request you send to Mule (no need to modify the config of BIG-IP at this point).